# Making a website in ASP.NET, and can't get the browser scrollbar to work

Tags: asp.net, scroll, scrollbar

I'm new to web development, so maybe this is an easy issue to resolve, but currently I'm stumped.

I'm making this website - http://www.astranavis.com, and can't get the browser scrollbar to work.  (I don't want to have to insert it into the globalContainer div tag, I want the scrollbar to automatically appear in the browser if the browser window is minimized).

I've tried inserting overflow-y:scroll into the body tag in css, and while it creates the actual scrollbar in the browser, it doesn't actually scroll.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `position: fixed;` in your global container.  the way you're centering it is.. strange to say the least.  Instead, use `margin: 0 auto;` to center it horizontally.  Also, get rid of the negative margin.